# Is there a way I can set the value of a file upload so it doesn't whipe on page refresh

Tags: php, file-upload

Before my page is submitted, PHP is used to verify the integrity of all my data.  I am currently using `if(isset($_POST['bannerTitle'])){ echo htmlentities($_POST['bannerTitle']);}` to keep the set values of my input data fields, but when the page is redrawn my uploaded file data is naturally reset to null.

Is there anything I can do to keep the selected users selected img file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file uploads doesnt store any post data by default, but you can use `$_FILE['fieldname']['name']` to retrieve its name and store at your database.